# FPGA implementation of temperature sensor data in 7 segment display

Tags: sensors, fpga, lcd

I want to know about project related to temperature sensor , like the temperature 80 degrees is sensed the it will send signal to FPGA and it should display "error" into seven segment display. and temperature sensor is connected to one machine and FPGA is connected to the generator, both the machines are connected to each other though for supply voltage. how to integrate both?? Please help...

Comment: Why are you trying to use an FPGA for this? Without knowing any further details, I suggest you look into using a microcontroller.

Comment: @MTCoster My project requires me to implement it in FPGA..... Pls help if you could....

Comment: You should be able to connect both the temperature sensor and the seven segment display to the FPGA, depends on your requirements - or is there something I am missing here..? You should be able to get a FPGA board with a seven segment and general IO pins where you could connect a _compatible_ sensor.